# Get nearby places without using a search term

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to find a way to use the Google Places API to return a list of places in a given area (with the current location at the centre). The closest I have got to achieving this is with `GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions`. However, this requires a search term string (as if the user were typing the search) and an empty string returns 0 results. I want a way to return ALL places in a given area and not have to narrow this with any search term.

I have also tried `PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace` which returns nearby places with no requirement of a search term, but you can't control the area and the range seems to be very small indeed (as expected due to the purpose of the method).

It appears to be possible using the web API but I can't find how to do it within the Android one. Is it even possible?

I should also add that I don't want this in a map (so I can't use the `PlacePicker`); I am building a custom list of places.